# How to upload webpage on FTP server

Tags: ftp

I want to use ftp server hosting for my webpage.I need to download ftp server or
else is there any other way like default ftp server so i can use, suggest me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a service you can use:

https://www.godaddy.com/help/ftp-how-to-upload-files-96